# Untrappable error/response using GetJsonAsync in Blazor with an API producing an HTTP Response of 204 'No Content '

Tags: c#, json, api, asynchronous, blazor

```
public async Task<E.Translations> LoadTranslations(int Id)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            E.Translations Translations = new E.Translations();
            Translations = await client.GetJsonAsync<E.Translations>(Config.GetEndpointURI($"{TRANSLATION}{Id}")).ConfigureAwait(true);
            return Translations;
        }
    }
```

When using the pattern above to load *JSON* data into a class, in this case Translations, the method works as expected when a set of data is received with an HTTP 200 OK.

However, when an HTTP response of 204, 'No Content', is returned from the API the process appears to proceed no further with no examinable value of the class to be populated.

I've attempted examining the class for null and also tried wrapping a try/catch block around the `GetJsonAsync` part of the method to no avail. The process seems to halt at the `GetJsonAsync` call and with debugging being rather thin on the ground with Blazor it's not easy to determine what's actually happening at this point.

What I'd ideally like to accomplish would be to test the class to be populated for null or any other property value but this doesn't seem possible at the moment?

Comment: Why do you use the HttpClient with a using block ? I guess you're using client-side Blazor, right ? If so, you should inject the HttpClient service into your component. If not, you shouldn't use GetJsonAsync at all, event if you could.

Comment: Thanks enet. This code is contained within a class outside of any Blazor component, (.razor), file. The basis of the code is client-side Blazor but I'm separating the code into Blazor components calling other classes, not embedding the C# code within the .razor file.